# How to filter elements in List where predicate is over entire other List

Tags: scala

How to filter a List l1 where if an element in other List l2 is contained in l1.

Given two Lists ls1 , ls2 :

```
val ls1 = List("a b c" , "a c d" , "d e f")
val ls2 = List("a" , "c")
```

`List("a b c" , "a c d")` should be retured as "a" & "c" match with ls2 from ls1.

This is closest I've come up with but List is not filtered. I'm not sure how to define a `containsInList` function :

```
scala> val ls1 = List("a b c" , "a c d" , "d e f")
ls1: List[String] = List(a b c, a c d, d e f)

scala> val ls2 = List("a" , "c")
ls2: List[String] = List(a, c)

scala> ls1.filter(f => ls2.contains(f)).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `exists` method on `ls2`:

```
ls1.filter(f => ls2.exists(f.contains))
```